# Getting GoogleJsonResponseException 401 Unauthorized exception when getting info from google calendar

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm getting the following exception when trying to get data from google calendar Please note that I'm using simple API key :
Exception in thread "main"

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Login Required",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Login Required"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

Here is code :

```
Calendar calendar = new Calendar.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),JSON_FACTORY,null).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new CalendarRequestInitializer(API_KEY))
            .build();
    List<CalendarListEntry> calendars = calendar.calendarList().list().execute().getItems();// getting exception here
```

Here is my dependencies related to google :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
    <version>v3-rev305-1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

API key was create by the following guide : 
[https://docs.simplecalendar.io/google-api-key/](http://Google-API-KEY)

Answer (score 1):

[401 means invalid authorization header.](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials)

> The access token you're using is either expired or invalid.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization",
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Try to do the following:

> - Get a new access token using the long-lived refresh token.
> - If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described    in [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth).
> - If you are seeing this for a service account, check that you have    successfully completed all the steps in the [service account page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing null credentials as the 3rd parameter in Calendar.Builder
That's why you are getting 401.

Comment: Dmitri what credentials needed for that ? I thought it should work in this way as in example